# Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have following code:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-type: text/xml' );
mysql_connect( 'domain', 'user', 'password' );
mysql_select_db( 'database' );

mysql_query("   INSERT INTO user(userName,password,email)
                VALUES(

                    '".$_POST['username']."',
                    '".md5($pass)."',
                    '".$_POST['email']."',          
 )" );
?>
```

When i try to load this in url:

http://xcode.domain.de/add.php?userName=test&password=test

I got this error on my server:

Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in /kunden//webseiten/xcode/add.php on line 15

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in /kunden/webseiten/xcode/add.php on line 15

can Somebody help on this?

thank you

Comment: This is like the textbook example of script injection vulnerable.

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Your variables appear to be coming from the URI QUERY_STRING which are populated into `$_GET` in PHP, not `$_POST`.  @crush meant that you do not sanitize your input before attempting to insert the values into the database.  So if I made my username `Milo';DROP TABLE user--` then you might have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII 39 (decimal) is a single apostrophe.

The error that I see is an extra comma after the "email" line.  Try this:

```
                '".$_POST['username']."',
                '".md5($pass)."',
                '".$_POST['email']."'
```

Comment: doesn't work

my sql table look like this:


    id         bigint(20)  
    added         timestamp            ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    userName varchar(64) utf8_unicode_ci
    password varchar(32) utf8_unicode_ci
    email         varchar(20) utf8_unicode_ci

something wrong here?

i think not and how must i put the email adress in the URL? is there a problem with the "@"?

Comment: sorry for the bad format..how can i attach something here..would be more easier... :)

Comment: okay, he add a timestamp, a id, and always the same password, but not email adresse or user name.

Is the URL right?

add.php?userName=test2&password=test2&email=test2@de.de